# Django postgresql model constraint on Charfield

Tags: django, postgresql

I'm using Django and Postgresql. I've created a CharField in a model, with db_collation of type 'case_insensitive'. I added a unique_together constraint for that field and another field. Seems like the DB identifies '1', '01', '001' as the same, although it's a string (charField), so I'm getting this error message when trying to create different objects with those values -

```
psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation: duplicate key value violates unique constraint...
```

I don't understand why it identifies them as the same value although it's a string (and it actually saved as '1', '01', '001'... and not all as '1' for example)
This is the field in the model:

```
my_identifier = models.CharField(db_collation="case_insensitive", db_index=True, max_length=100, null=True)
```

This is the collation definition:

```
CreateCollation(
        "case_insensitive",
        provider="icu",
        locale="und-u-ks-level2-kn-true",
        deterministic=False,
    )
```

And this is the unique_together definition:

```
unique_together = ('my_identifier', 'container_id')
```

Comment: All databases have some kids Nd of automatically converting, in your cases to int

Comment: More information needed: 1) The table definition as shown in Postgres, preferably using `psql` and then `\d table_name`  2) The complete error message. You left out the part that identified the actual conflict 3) Postgres and Django versions 4) What is result  in `psql` when you do `select '1' = '01';`?

Comment: could you share your models.py file?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, setting the collation with `kn-true` is the reason for that. I've tried with and without it. This option basically allows to alphanumeric sort by that field.